# How to get rid of specific warning messages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

A lot of times I like to write try catch blocks like so:

```
try
{
    // do stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Normally, I want to see warning messages telling me that I have an unused variable.  However, in this case I put it there and don't use it on purpose (I do vb6/.net interop code and it allows me to ignore an error, but still let me have access to the exception while debugging with the .net ide attached to vb6).

Is there a way that I could specifically get rid of warning messages that say:

"The variable 'ex' is declared but never used"?

I'm thinking that I would either have to get rid of all warnings about unused variables or else just live with these ones that I don't want to see, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `#pragma warning` to diable a warning in your code, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought about that but I don't really want to turn off this warning entirely... just for this specific scenario.  I settled on just including a line of code that says "var SupressWarningMessage = ex;".

Comment: @BrandonMoore: If you only want the warning disabled on one line then you can turn it off with a pragma and turn it back on with another pragma.

Comment: True, but that is uglier and requires more typing that just assigning it to a variable.  But I marked yours the answer because that is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't define a variable then (just name the type):

```
try {
    // ...
}
catch (Exception) {
    // ...
}
```

Just note that depending on what you're doing simply "dropping" exceptions without actually doing anything about them could be considered bad design.

Comment: The point is that when I'm debugging I would like to see information about the exception.  If I don't provide a variable to hold it then I can't do that that I'm aware of.

Comment: Ah, okay. Preprocessor stuff would probably be the best solution in that case. You could try using `ex;` as the only line within the `catch()` block, but I'm not sure if that's viable/possible in C# (only used it in C++ so far).

Comment: Don't think that would work, but I'll try it soon and find out.  In the meantime I've done the next best thing by just writing "var SuppressWarningMessage = ex;".  It does the job and I think it's descriptive enough that someone else reading it will understand it's purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I could specifically get rid of warning messages?

Set compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
2. Click the Build property page.
3. Modify the Warning Level property.

Comment: Not 'specifically get rid of warning messages', but 'get rid of specific warning messages'.  Slight difference in meaning there :)